# Binding a ListBox with ValueMember

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I extended the ListBox to built my CustomListbox.

It will accept the classobject array as datasource and I override OnDrawItem() to display them by reading the classobject array.

Upto here everything is working fine. The problem is I am not able to read the ValueMember of the Listbox because I havent assigned it. I want to add one of the property of my classObject as Value Member

Pseudo Code:

```
public class myModel
{
  int id;
  string name;
  XXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXX
}

myModel[] ds = getData();
//myCustomListbox.ValueMember = "id";   //this doesnt seem to work
myCustomListbox.DataSource =ds;
```

I repeat, the OnDrawItem() will draw the required display values. Is there any method i can override like this to add the Value Items also?

Answer (score 1):

Binding works with properties only. Change your field to property (and make sure it is public - by default class members are private)

```
public class myModel
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

Now all should be OK:

```
myModel[] ds = getData();
myCustomListbox.ValueMember = "id";
myCustomListbox.DataSource = ds;
```

BTW C# [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggest to use Pascal Names for properties, methods and type names.

Comment: @Rams is your property marked as public? Also can you show how you are reading value member?

Comment: Yes they are all public and value of a is always empty(after clicking item also) `string a = myCustomListBox.ValueMember` inside SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: @Rams make sure have assigned `ValueMember` to appropriate list box. This code should work without problem - on selected index changed you should see `ValueMember` equal to `"id"` and `SelectedValue` should be id of selected model

Comment: Not sure why this is not working. I am managing with this for now. `MyModel mod= (MyModel)myCustomListbox.SelectedItem; string a= mod.id;`

Comment: @Rams it's not clear what you are doing. `mod.id` is integer and you are trying to assign it to string

Answer (score 0):

**ListBox binding with a data table in C# (in windows applications) is necessary to add the value members.**

***If we make the code without value member like as follows,***

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table1",con);
        da.Fill(dt);

        listBox1.DataSource = dt;
        // listBox1.ValueMember = "data";  //data is one of the coloumn of the table...

    }
```

**The output for the above code is given below**

System.Data.DataRowView

System.Data.DataRowView

System.Data.DataRowView

**If we provide value member in code like as follows**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table1",con);
    da.Fill(dt);
    listBox1.DataSource = dt;
    listBox1.ValueMember = "data";  //data is one of the coloumn of the table...
  }
```

**The output will be...**

The list of the particular column in the table. here 'data' .